# JAXB : how to read the xsi:type value when unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am using **JAXB** in the **XSD** / **XML** to Java direction. My **XSD** contains derived types and the **XML** I have to unmarshall contain **xsi:type** attributes. Looking at the code **JAXB** (the default Sun implementation) has generated (for the unmarshalling) there seems to appear no methods to get these attributes.

Is it because I can always do a `getClass()` on the unmarshalled Java object and find the actual class?

Still, would it not be the case that depending on the packages or classes I provide to the `JAXBContext.newInstance` some base class may be instantiated instead? (one that is a superclass of the class corresponding to the actual value of the **xsi:type** attribute). In such a case being able to read the value of the actual attribute as it appears in the XML instance could be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will take care of everything for you. JAXB considers that each class corresponds to a complex type.  It has an algorithm for figuring out the type name, but you can override this using the `@XmlType` annotation.  When an element is unmarshalled if it contains an `xsi:type` attribute then JAXB will look to see if there is a class associated with that type.  If there is it will instantiate a class of that type, if not it will instantiate the type that corresponds to that element based on the mapping metadata supplied via annotations.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

---

**UPDATE**

Below is an example that may help:

**schema.xsd**

In the XML schema below the complex type `canadianAddress` extends the complexType `address`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/customer" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/customer" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="customer">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="address" type="tns:address"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

    <complexType name="address">
        <sequence>
            <element name="street" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="canadianAddress">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="tns:address">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="postalCode" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below the XML will be converted to the JAXB model generated from the above XML schema, and then converted back to XML.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.example.customer");

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/org/example/customer/input.xml");
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

Below is the XML.  The `address` element is qualified with `xsi:type` to indicate that it holds an instance of `canadianAddress` instead of just an `address`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer xmlns="http://www.example.org/customer">
    <address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="canadianAddress">
        <street>1 A Street</street>
        <postalCode>Ontario</postalCode>
    </address>
</customer>
```

Comment: Actually I checked your blog article before posting here but it seemed to be focused in the Java to XML direction. So basically, xsi:type doesn't survive the unmarshalling?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - It definitely does.  Is there a class that corresponds to the value of the xsi:type attribute?

Comment: yes, there is a corresponding class. I am just speculating that if such a class isn't available in the JAXBContext, then JAXB will likely instantiate a superclass in which case we'll have some kind of "information loss". But I haven't tried to reproduce this last hypothetical situation.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - Are you using the package name when you create the JAXBContext (i.e. `JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo");`

Comment: In this particular case, yes, a colon-separated list of package names. Other times I've used object factories or even a full, detailed enumeration of all classes (when I hit this problem: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-962)